# Group by and aggregate unique values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with following values

```
col1   col2   col3  
10002  en     tea   
10002  es     te
10002  ru     te
10003  en     coffee
10003  de     kaffee
10003  nl     kaaffee
```

I would like to group by col1 and aggregate the values of col3 if col2 values are other than 'en'. The expected output is:

```
col1   Term Name  Synonyms
10002  tea        te
10003  coffee     kaffee | kaaffee
```

I am running following code to achieve this:

```
# group the data and concatenate the terms
grouped = df.groupby(['col1'])
        .agg({'col3': lambda x: ' | '.join(x[df['col2'] != 'en'])})\
        .reset_index()

# merge the original data with the grouped data
df_result = pd.merge(df[df['col2'] == 'en'], grouped, on=['col1'], how='left')
df_result = df_result [['col1', 'col3_x', 'col3_y']]
df_result .columns = ['col1', 'Term Name', 'Synonyms']
```

How can I get the unique value for col3 per col1 (eg 'te'). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: A simple solution is just adding `set()` around the input to the `join` method, like so:
```.agg({'col3': lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x[df['col2'] != 'en']))})\```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is filter `en` rows by mask and join aggregate values with removed duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
m = df['col2'] != 'en'

df1 = df[m].drop_duplicates(['col1','col3']).groupby('col1')['col3'].agg(' | '.join)
df = (df.loc[~m, ['col1','col3']].merge(df1, on='col1')
         .rename(columns={'col3_x':'Term Name','col3_y':'Synonyms'}))
print (df)
    col1 Term Name          Synonyms
0  10002       tea                te
1  10003    coffee  kaffee | kaaffee
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
f = lambda x: ' | '.join(dict.fromkeys(x))
df = (df.assign(new=np.where(df['col2'].eq('en'), 'Term Name','Synonyms'))
        .pivot_table(index='col1', columns='new', values='col3', aggfunc=f)
            [['Term Name','Synonyms']]
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
    col1 Term Name          Synonyms
0  10002       tea                te
1  10003    coffee  kaffee | kaaffee
```